# How can I set the Element vertically center using scrollToElement in iScroll4

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar, iscroll

Is it possible to set element vertically or horizontally center with `iScroll` `scrollToElement`.
In `iScroll 5` `scrollToElement` have a options for centering a element, but not in `iScroll 4` and I am using `iScroll 4` for some reasons and I can not update `iScroll 4` to `iScroll 5`.

Comment: You already asked this question [here](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues). And that's the place it belongs to.

Comment: @blex Yeah I asked this question at GitHub also & here also that's because I require a solution as much as possible early.